# py UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start_time' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

edited..
full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dscli.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "dscli.py", line 31, in main
    instance_StreamingDownloader.download_all()
  File "file.py", line 283, in download_all
    time_first_frame_last_segment = self.get_time_saved_segment(crrt_segment - 1)
  File "file.py", line 239, in get_time_saved_segment
    return(start_time)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start_time' referenced before assignment
```

[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ophui.jpg)

It gets only first segment and then error.

How can I solve this issue?

code from [github](https://github.com/jerabaul29/CaptureStreaming)

Comment: What is `start_time` if `line[0: 14] == 'ID_START_TIME='` is false?

Comment: There's not enough information here for someone to really answer your question. Try adding the full traceback, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is quite simple - 
the condition allows some case when start_time is not defined during script run
so as it is not defined - it fails

Comment: and please ask questions with better context - screenshot with no syntax highlight is pretty stone age

Answer (score 0):

`start_time` is defined inside an `if` statement that's inside a `for` loop.

What if you don't enter the loop, or the condition isn't met? What should the function return?

`start_time` needs to be initialized (eg `start_time = 0 / None / False`) in the function body, outside any control flow clauses, so that it's always defined, and therefore you can always return it.

Answer (score 0):

when condition isn't met then:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dscli.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "dscli.py", line 31, in main
    instance_StreamingDownloader.download_all()
  File "file.py", line 286, in download_all
    lenght_ahead_buffered = time_first_frame_last_segment - time_if_streaming + random_perturbation
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

line 280-286:

```
while continue_download:
                time_first_frame_last_segment = self.get_time_saved_segment(crrt_segment - 1)

                time_if_streaming = time.time() - init_time
                random_perturbation = random.gauss(0, self.random_time)
                if self.verbose > 1:
                    print("time in video if streaming: " + str(time_if_streaming))
```